# php error with password_verify with ubuntu but works fine on xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I have some code that validates a password:

```
if(password_verify($password, $member['passwd'])){
    // set session variables
}
```

After verifying the password it redirects the user to the home page. 
I have verified that the query is successful from the DB and that $member['passwd'] exists and is the correct password. However it appears that my php script just stops running at that line. All echo's I added after that just don't get executed.

But when I run this on my Mac with XAMPP it works just fine and is able to log the user in. The code is exactly the same. Does anyone have any idea what the issue may be? It was working just about two weeks ago and there was no major code change that could have caused this. It could be an issue with an ubuntu/package update.

System info:
I am running PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 on Ubuntu 12.04.3 x64 where the error is occurring.
Locally I am using XAMPP for Mac and it's running PHP Version 5.5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password_verify` Is only supported on PHP 5.5+

It is most likely throwing an error but you have turned off displaying errors by setting `display_errors` to false in your `php.ini`.

You can either upgrade or use a compatibility library:

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

To upgrade you can use a PPA that provides later version of PHP for the version of Ubuntu you are using:

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5

Comment: The compatibility library fixed it. Thank you.